# Codeigniter + URL replacement issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing, codeigniter-2

The scenario is
I have to replace the http://www.example.com/index.php/controller/argument by 
http://www.example.com/controller/argument .

If somebody enter the index.php , mean uses 1st url then it should redirect to 404 error page.

As I am new on codeigniter, so can somebody please tell me how much ways are to implement this ? and what would be the best? Should I go for .htaccess or only route.php is sufficient to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You can find an answer in the documentation [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html). But basically all you have to do is to create an .htaccess file in your root directory. Mine looks like this:

    `RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]`

**EDIT:**

All you have to do:
 - Rename index.php in the root directory to something else;
 - Update /application/config/config.php where it says $config['index_page'] to use the newly renamed file.

Comment: This is not the solution however it did just opposite. It made index.php compulsory to traverse any url.

Comment: I am sorry, I read your question again, more thoroughly. If I am not mistaken again, you want to forbid any kind of requests to index.php, is that correct? If so, you will have to rename that index.php file to something else, and then update **$config['index_page']** in **/application/config/config.php**.

Don't forget to edit your .htaccess file as well, if you are using one of course.

Comment: Its still not working. Actually I wanted to rewrite rules with condition that whenever I got index.php after example.php, it redirect to a specified page that is show 404 error. Can you help me out for writing regular expression and rules with condition for it?

Comment: I don't think that you can get around with it like that. The reason is that you are actually always accessing index.php, it loads CodeIgniter's bootstrap. But even if it is possible to happen with a regular expression, I don't think that is a solution I would recommend. Why isn't working my last suggestion? I tested it here and works pretty fine - always 404 error when accessing index.php.

Comment: But the whole application stopped to work on renaming the index.php

Comment: Did you modify your /application/config/config.php file to use the newly renamed file, and did you check your .htaccess file?

Comment: What version of CodeIgniter are you using?

Comment: version 2.2.0 This is the latest version.

Comment: There has got to be some sort of issue with your settings, I just downloaded a fresh copy of CI 2.2, renamed index.php to home.php, changed configuration file and it works as expected.

Comment: Heh that was something. I will edit my answer to conclude everything written down so far. I am glad I could help.